# Can I use the octopus cable to connect a Thunderbolt Display to my 2012 iMac?

Tags: imac, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I tried connecting a Thunderbolt Display to my 27" iMac (2012) using the Thunderbolt end of the display’s octopus cable, but the display did not turn on and was not recognised by the iMac.

Is this configuration not supported, i.e. does it only work when using a Thunderbolt <-> Thunderbolt cable?

Comment: What version of Mac OS X are you using? Have you run Software Update to install all available software and firmware updates?

Comment: The iMac is running 10.8.4 with all updates installed. I tested the display on a MacBook Pro, there it works fine.

I also checked in System Profiler. It lists no devices connected to either of the Thunderbolt ports, even though the display is plugged in.

Comment: If you go to Utilities > System Information > Thunderbolt while it's plugged into the MacBook Pro, what is listed for the firmware version?